# Does the anti-rust properties of bluing carbon steel disappear at a certain temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, energy, temperature

Yesterday I blued my new carbon steel wok over a very high (200K BTU) burner which is capable of getting the wok to 1000+ degrees with ease.

I understand that bluing adds a rust-resistant layer which is triggered by a chemical reaction at around around [575 F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h930a.png).

In this case I decided to blue the wok all the way up to 1100-1200 F given that this will be used on a very high temperature stove, and while I won't cook at those temps, the pan itself will get that hot from time to time (through accident, burning off stuck on oil, etc).

As I was doing this it brought some questions to mind. I tried researching but I have no knowledge of chemistry so I came here instead.

1. Does the rust-resistant property of tempered carbon steel vanish after you leave the blue temperature zone? In this case, I got it to the "very slight red" or "slight red" zone.
2. Are other properties affected as well at these temperature zones, in addition to rust resistance? It seemed from Googling that hardness is likely plummeting, which I suppose isn't important for a wok. It got me to thinking what else is changing in this pan.

Thanks!

In process:

[image]

Completed:

[image]

Comment: Those are temper colors caused by different thickness of iron oxides. Little or no rust protection. The time at temperature can be estimated by the colors. Gold > pink > blue > purple, nominally. They thicken with longer time and higher temperature. Stainless steels go through the same color changes (in air) at higher temperatures.